# php mysql query first letter !=[a-z]

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE text = 'a%' 
(this can get all the `text` fields which begin with the letter "a".)
```

But how to get the fields where the first letter !=[a-z]?

for example:

```
\"hello\"  // this first letter begin as \ not range in a-z
いけ  // also first letter not begin range in a-z
... 
may also have a white space as the first character.
```

So how can you use php mysql query to get all these kinds of results where the first letter `!=[a-z]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE text REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z]';
```

That is if you want it to be case insensitive (uppercase or lowercase). If you want to allow uppercase letters A-Z then just use:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE text REGEXP '^[^a-z]';
```

Essentially the regular expression says match any string that doesn't have letters a-z at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`REGEXP`/`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE text REGEXP '^[^a-z]'
```

Answer (score 2):

A non-REGEXP solution is to use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE LEFT(text, 1) NOT BETWEEN 'a' AND 'Z';
```

This should be faster than using REGEXP, since MySQL can use indexes on BETWEEN queries, while it cannot on REGEXP queries.

However, I have no benchmarks available, should not be to hard to test though.

Comment: MySQL will not use the index on text as you have wrapped it in a function. You have to isolate the indexed field in the comparison in the where statement for mysql to use an index on it.

Comment: @Riedsio what do you mean? `LEFT` can utilize indices.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE text NOT REGEXP '^[a-z]';
```